# https request working on chrome but not on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-chrome, http, https

I am trying to make an iOS app using swift that requests data from a server. The server is running on https and when accessed using chrome, it works fine. But when I try the iOS request, it gives me an error "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)"

I tried all the answers given about allowing unsecured domains, but this is a secured domain (https not http).

My iOS code is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/homescreen.php?variablex=something")        
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)as! String)
    self.embedLink = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)as! String
```

When I run the app and open it in the emulator it crashes when I click the screen with this code in it and displays `"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"` on the third line - after `as! String)`

And suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this SSL self-signed?, please post your code.

Comment: No it is signed using startssl.com. What code would help?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I solved the issue.

Turns out there was a chain file missing on the server, that although seemed fine when using a browser like chrome or firefox, iOS was more specific in their requirements.

I used https://certificatechain.io/ to generate this crt file and it worked perfect since putting it in the server.